# ImportError: cannot import name caches

Tags: python, django, database

I am using Django 1.6. I want to start working site. When you use `python manage.py shell` get an error:

```
(test) D:\test>python manage.py shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\testvenv\lib\site-packages\constance\backends\database\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
ImportError: cannot import name caches
```

Tell me what I have a problem. And if it can depend on your database (not sure that Django is connected to the DB - I do not know how to check)?

Added:

Code `manag.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your `manage.py`

Comment: @MrLeeh I added code `manage.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it you're using `django-constance`.

According to [their change log](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#v1-1-2015-09-24), they haven't supported 1.6 since version 1.1

So either use an older version of that, or better yet - use a supported version of django.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.7/#cache), `django.core.cache.caches` was introduced in Django 1.7, so this application has never worked with Django 1.6.

If you have a running instance of that application, check which version of Django it actually uses.